# loadHTML & loadHTMLFile, which one is faster?

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

Between these two, which one is faster? Getting content directly by `loadHTMLFile` or first by `cURL` and then pass to `loadHTML`

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
@$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);
```

Or

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$ch = curl_init();
$timeout = 500;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
@$doc->loadHTML($data);
```

Comment: It's faster to type the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add as the last line of your script and try each method at least 3 times to get an accurate idea of which is fastest.

```
Page generated in 
<?php echo  round((microtime(TRUE)-$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT']), 4); ?>
 seconds on <?php echo date("M jS Y"); ?>
```